# Function returns true, but then it becomes false upon assignment

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I call a function (SaveChanges) to access my business / data layer and save any changes to fields that are marked as an Add or Update and are marked to be processed. This function used to work fine up until 60+ minutes ago.

What is happening is that suddenly the function is returning false. After debugging through the code, when it hits Return the local boolean is set as True ... but when it gets back to the calling method (and uses the return value) it is now False.

As I said I went through line by line and debugged it, then I added a watch to it. The funny part is that there is one spot that sets the boolean to false, and when I put a breakpoint on that spot it is never reached.

Here is the function:

```
Private Function SaveChanges() As Boolean

    Dim blnSaved As Boolean = True

    Dim saveableRows As List(Of DataRow) = (From d As DataRow In _listData.Tables(0).Rows _
                                            Where Not d("Marking") = "Duplicate" _
                                            And d("Process") = True _
                                            Select d).ToList()


    If saveableRows.Count > 0 Then

        For Each drRow As DataRow In saveableRows

            Dim data As IDataEntity = DataEntities.GetData(_tableName)

            If drRow("Marking") = "Update" Then

                'UPDATE
                data.UpdateItem(drRow.ItemArray)

            Else

                'ADD
                data.AddItem(drRow.ItemArray)

            End If

            If data.HasErrors Then

                blnSaved = False 'Never reaches this part ... !?!?!

            End If

        Next

    Else

        blnSaved = True

    End If

End Function
```

And here is how I'm using the function:

```
If SaveChanges() Then

        Dim frmTableView As frmTableView = New frmTableView(_listData.Tables(0).TableName)

        If Not Me.MdiParent Is Nothing Then

            frmTableView.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent

        End If

        frmTableView.Show()

        Me.Close()

    Else

        MessageBox.Show("Unable to save the list. IT has been notified.", "Save Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    End If
```

I'm spending too much time on this and figured it was time to look for help.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldnt SaveChanges(..) have a return statement?

Comment: HAHAHA LMFAO ... that must have been deleted somehow ... or I'm just an idiot ... I will let you all decide :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're never returning your boolean. Add:

```
Return blnSaved
```

at the bottom of the function.

Comment: @Tony Abrams - or just to step away from it for a bit and then go back to it once it's out of your brain. I've made this mistake so many times it's not even funny.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler warn you about this? Is this compiler warning turned on: "function/operator without return value"

Comment: @MarkJ - with the settings I keep in my own studio, if I look at it wrong it warns me. But it's entirely possible to have a lax environment set up that would not throw a warning or error for this (another reason moving to C# is usually not a bad idea).

Comment: ... Sadly the compiler warning "function/operator without return value" doesn't seem to catch Boolean functions without return values. I suppose because the default return value is False. Pity

Comment: @MarkJ - now that you mention it, I believe C# is the same way. I think int return values behave similar with a return of 0, but I can't recall.

Answer (score 1):

You never assign the function return value.  You'll get its default value, False.  Instead of assigning to the local variable (blnSaved), assign to SaveChanges instead.  Or add Return blnSaved at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you just missing a `Return blnSaved` at the end of your function?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you are simply missing Return blnSaved statement.  I would also suggest that you do not need the following else statement because you are already initializing the blnSaved value at the start of the method.

```
 Else

        blnSaved = True

 End If
```

Comment: +1 for the effort.  I added the extra else as a way of forcing the true and since the problem is fixed it will be removed.